# Which function wants to know position/geolocation?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, coords

I am trying to improve a website taken over by a previous agency and I can't figure out which function attempts to get the user's location, as I would like to get rid of it. The location prompt is part of the used WordPress theme as it disappears when being changed. That's why I've been checking all JS files of the theme and the browser console when loading the page for functions like *geotargeting, position, location, coords, longitude, latitude, and more* but I can't find a thing.

Is there a way to find out which function triggers the location request in the browser? I am looking for general hints about JS functions that ask the user for his location, other than the ones I've already tried.
For reference, here's also a [link to the website](https://dieplanbar.online/).

I feel like I am missing something but after hours of crawling through all the JS files I'd like to know if I've overlooked something obvious. I will be graceful for any hint.

Comment: Unfortunately questions that summarize to a request for users to go to a third party website and debug it, are off topic for the site.  Questions on StackOverflow are expected to be self contained.

Comment: Fair enough, however my main question is: Which other function or "trigger" than of all those I already looked for could query the user for his location? As I already mentioned, it can only be a JS thing and it's part of the theme. I feel like I am missing something obvious here but I can't find out.

Comment: To answer that, I would have to go to the site and debug it.  But as I already stated, that is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Geolocation calls are done through the geolocation API, located at `window.navigator.geolocation`.

If you have a huge number of scripts and you can't search through all of them individually, you can patch `window.navigator.geolocation` to throw an error when it's accessed, then examine the stack trace:

```
Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'geolocation', { get() { throw new Error('Geolocation call is here') }})
```

(this should only be used for debugging, of course - it should not exist in production code)

Your geolocation call is in this script:

https://t2w2a8u6.rocketcdn.me/wp-content/themes/die-planbar/js/scripts.js?ver=1.0.4

```
    $(window).load(function () {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } 
        
        
    });
```